# Watir is able to see element, but can't interact with it

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir

My html structure is follow:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPane$Password" type="password" id="ctl00_ContentPane_Password">
```

From the UI this is how it looks:

[image]

My ruby script is follow:

`browser.text_field(:id => 'ctl00_ContentPane_Password').wait_until_present(10)` - returns **true**

...well then this command:

`browser.text_field(:id => 'ctl00_ContentPane_Password').set ('test')` - returns error message

```
Session: [Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException] unable to locate element, using {:id=>"ctl00_ContentPane_Password", :tag_name=>"input or textarea", :type=>"(any text type)"}
```

Anyone is familiar with these type of ridiculous issues with Watir?

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Then element is not visible. This happen because there might be two element with the same id and first one is hidden. So write this code and check it.

```
 browser.text_fields(:id => 'ctl00_ContentPane_Password')[1].set 'test'
```

Remember, you don't need to use `wait_until_present` because waiting is automatic

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.input(id: 'ctl00_ContentPane_Password').send_keys('your-text')
```